# Spring 3.0 MVC problem -- requested resource() is not available

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm trying to learn Spring MVC, using Spring 3.1 jars, and I'm getting the following error message in my browser.

```
HTTP Status 404 - /list_cars.html

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message /list_cars.html

description The requested resource (/list_cars.html) is not available.
```

The error occurs when I click on the link in index.jsp (source below).

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Spring 3.0 MVC Tutorial</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="/list_cars.html">Get Car List</a>
</body>
</html>
```

carList.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<head><title>Car List</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Car List</h1>

<c:forEach items="${carList}" var="car">
        ${car.brand.name} ${car.model}: ${car.price}
        <br />
</c:forEach>

</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Spring3MVC</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <bean name="/list_cars.html" class="springmvc.web.CarListController"/>
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the file "list_cars.html"?

If you are trying to get the "carsList.jsp" then you need to change the link .

I suggest you look at the spring sample projects which can be found

[Spring downloads page](http://www.springsource.org/download)

Comment: I've removed the prefix statement from spring-servlet.xml, and I moved my jsp to outside of /WEB-INF.  I also changed the link in index.jsp.  I now have carList.jsp being called, which is correct, but nothing is being returned from the controller.  Since that's a separate problem, that calls for a separate thread.